# Midnight Commander (mc) not working in cygwin ("Error opening terminal")

Tags: cygwin, xterm, mc

I installed Midnight Commander into my Cygwin environment, but it's not working.  Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
$ mc
Error opening terminal: xterm.
$ mc -U
Error opening terminal: xterm.
```

Here's the version information for `mc`:

```
$ mc -V
  GNU Midnight Commander 4.6.1
  Virtual File System: tarfs, extfs, cpiofs, ftpfs, fish
  With builtin Editor
  Using the ncurses library
  With optional subshell support
  With mouse support on xterm
  With support for X11 events
```

...and here's the version of Cygwin:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 c40920j 1.7.7(0.230/5/3) 2010-08-31 09:58 i686 Cygwin
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is not programming related and thus better off at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You might see this error if your copy of `xterm` is missing; you should find it under:

```
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm
```

Comment: I can find xterm in the dir: /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm